# root project in flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle

hey this is my first app on flutter i got this problem when I run it and I don't know what to do please help:

```
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
```

Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :cloud_firestore_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\nouhaila\AndroidStudioProjects\elearning\android\build.gradle' line: 35
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have written a little code it might be simplest to start a new project. Start by compiling the starting counter app. After that works you can add more code with every step.